# Import of large itunes epf database is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, itunes, large-files, epf

I'm trying to import EPF relational database. Itunes epf relational database is consist of details of all database ( application,music,tv shows,games etc). You can find more on this here [Itunes EPF Relation Database](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed.html) I can be able to import all database except one database which is not processing. This file is around 6gb.

```
$field_separator = chr(1);
                                $record_separator = chr(2)."\n";   
                                $data_appdt=explode($record_separator,file_get_contents('file_path',true));
                                    foreach ($data_appdt as $key => $value) 
                                    {
                                    if (substr($value, 0, 1) != '#')
                                        {
                                            if (!empty($value))
                                            {
                                            {
                                                $data_itu_app_dt=explode($field_separator, $value);
                                                $result=$this->admin_model->itunes_app_dt($data_itu_app_dt);
                                            }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
```

The above code is done in codeigniter which is the controller for the import process.This code works for around upto 2gb file. But for size larger than that its not working. Maybe its reading the whole file and memory doesn't allow it to do so. So i used the below code for processing higher files.

```
    $handle = fopen('file_path', "r") or die("Couldn't get handle");
                            if ($handle) {
                            while (!feof($handle)) {
                            $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
                            $data_appp=explode($record_separator,$buffer);
                            foreach ($data_appp as $key => $value) 
                            {
                            if (substr($value, 0, 1) != '#')
                            {
                                if (!empty($value))
                                {
                                    $data_itu_appp=explode($field_separator, $value);
                                    //print_r($data_itu_appp);
                                    $result=$this->admin_model->itunes_appp($data_itu_appp);
                                }
                            }   
                            }
                                }
                            fclose($handle);
                                }
```

It works for even 8gb files and the import is done and completed successfully. But then for a 6gb file the import is not going on. This is the sample data for the table

> 1426669253786|329704232|EN|iParrot Phrase Vietnamese-Italian|Translate
>   Vietnamese Phrase to Italian Taking-with Translator for
>   iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch|
>
> iParrot Phrase sets a new standard for instant multi-language
>   translation software. Designed exclusively for the iPad/iPhone/iPod
>   Touch, it’s stocked with over 20 kinds of perfectly pronounced oral
>   language for instant use. iParrot Phrase is organized into categories
>   such as: Greetings, Transportation, Shopping, and Asking for helping
>   etc. So it is enough for you to find the sentences you need instantly.
>   Organized for instant access and ease, it is especially useful while
>   traveling abroad. Virtual fluency available in Chinese, English,
>   Japanese, Russian, French, German, Spanish, Italian, Korean,
>   Portuguese, Arabic, Thai and Vietnamese.
>
> - NO INTERNET ACCESS NEEDED!
> - Universal App for iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch;
> - Learn foreign language wherever you go;
> - Listen and practice pronouncing phrases on the screen;
> - Romanized pronunciation guides (Romanization/PinYin) for Arabic, Chinese, Japanese, Korean, Russian and Thai;
> - 400 practical travel phrases at your fingertip;
> - Perfect for students and business travelers.|iOS 5 support; UI improvement; Content correction; Bug
>     fix.|http://www.iparrot.info|http://www.iparrot.info|http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/59/4c/3c/594c3c1d-8081-583a-0a02-3d07edb41f85/screen320x480.jpeg|http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/ba/36/43/ba3643ff-1316-a689-a422-c67eff2e1639/screen320x480.jpeg|http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/5a/17/43/5a174333-d3c7-6ae5-5e25-6539e3d9e62c/screen320x480.jpeg|320x480|320x480|320x480|http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/2e/87/2d/2e872d35-d55b-8910-0f2b-bb9042f57537/screen480x480.jpeg|360x480|

This is the sample data from that database which is application detail ( In above the sample data that i replaced ASCII characters (SOH) for new field with |). Actually when the import is in process using the second code when the new line comes its taking it as /n and the import getting broken. So is there any ways to get around this or any other method to process such large file (6 GB) for database import ? Maybe the above things are little confusing. Is there any clarification needed then i will make things more clear. Looking for a good solution.. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a *direct* answer for you in php, but the problem is very likely that you load the file in memory. The trick is to stream the file down and write it in chunks.

In python you could use the `requests` [library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for example, that does Auth nicely (and you could write your download logic maybe in an easier fashion.
It would look like something like this

```
username='yourusernamehere'
password='yourpasswordhere'
response = requests.get('https://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/', auth=(username, password), stream=True)
```

Note that I used the `stream=True` mechanism because you will be downloading huge files that probably will not fit in memory, you should use chunking like so:

```
 with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```

Comment: fgets work for larger files because it reads contents line by line. But if in content if there is /n or similar tags then stripping getting complicated and its giving wrong output.